# Can I use ModelMapper API in Java to update fields that have changed?

Tags: java, spring-rest, modelmapper

I am using ModelMapper API to convert my DTO objects to Entity objects and vice versa. It works fine if I'm doing a POST operation to create an Entity. What do I do to update an Entity? I want to avoid calling setter methods manually.

I want to update the fields the value of which has changed in the incoming DTO object.

Answer (score 2):

Model mapper has method which map source to existing destination object:

```
modelMapper.map(source, destination);
```

So, It will update destination object with new values from your DTO.